# GROUP BY with MAX(date), but the date is in two separate columns

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, max

I'm trying to get the list of IDs of all the rows with latest posting date for each author in a table, for example:

```
id    author_id   date
1     12          2020-12-23
2     12          2021-01-06
3     12          2021-04-12
4     12          2021-02-10
5     17          2021-09-16
6     17          2021-05-20
7     17          2021-02-23
8     17          2021-07-02
9     24          2021-03-24
10    24          2021-02-10
11    24          2020-08-18
12    24          2020-12-14
```

The desired result should be:

```
id
3
5
9
```

I used this query and it works perfect:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM (
      SELECT author_id, MAX(`date`) as MaxDate
      FROM `posts_log`
      GROUP BY author_id
) b
INNER JOIN `posts_log` a
ON a.author_id = b.author_id AND a.date = b.MaxDate
```

But let's imagine that situation changed. Now author is allowed to post only once per month. So the table changed too and 'date' column became separated:

```
id   author_id   month   year
1    12          12      2020
2    12          1       2021
3    12          4       2021
4    12          2       2021
5    17          9       2021
6    17          5       2021
7    17          2       2021
8    17          7       2021
9    24          3       2021
10   24          2       2021
11   24          8       2020
12   24          12      2020
```

Yeah, I know, looks a little bit stupid, but this wasn't my decision. Now I have such table and I'm not allowed to change the structure.
The question is: How to get the same result with this new table. Is it possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use similar logic. Just instead of the date, use a calculated value from year and month:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM (
      SELECT p.author_id, MAX(p.year*100+p.month) as MaxMonth
      FROM posts_log p
      GROUP BY p.author_id
) b
INNER JOIN posts_log a
ON a.author_id = b.author_id AND a.year*100+a.month = b.MaxMonth;
```